# How can multiple people do the same workout?

Tags: apple-watch, appletv, fitness+

We have subscribed as a family to Apple Fitness+ and have it via a TV with Apple TV. All family members have access to the Apple TV already via profiles.

It’s possible to have one person’s watch synchronised with the TV, but is there a way of allowing multiple people to do the same workout at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen a way to do this so I've thought it may be possible to start the exercise simultaneously on a iPhone/iPad and do the workout using the TV with another family member but still get your activity updated because you were paired on the phone.